# How does Telerik MVC extensions render template columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I've just been looking at the source code for the Telerik MVC extensions and can't for the life of me work out how the template columns work. I can **get** them to work just fine, but I'm trying to understand what is happening under the hood, as I think they are really useful. I've stepped through the source code but I'm still a bit confused. Here's an example from the source code's example project.

```
  Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Template(c => { 
            %><img 
                alt="<%= c.CustomerID %>" 
                src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Grid/Customers/" + c.CustomerID + ".jpg") %>" 
              /><% 
        }).Title("Picture");
        columns.Bound(c => c.ContactName).Title("Name");
        columns.Bound(c => c.Phone);
    })
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height(250))
    .Pageable()
    .Render();
```

The columns => {} delegate  is of type `Action<GridColumnFactory<T>>`
where Model is `IEnumerable<T>` and the c=>{} delegate is of type `Action<TModel>` . That much I understand, the Template method on the GridColumnFactory is given an action as a parameter.

**How is this action used to render the required HTML?**

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic here is that Telerik uses the fact that any content (HTML, JavaScript, etc) inside ASP.NET Web Pages is in fact translated into a [`Response.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1463ysyw.aspx)-like call by the page compiler.

For example;

```
<% Action action = () => { %><h1>Title</h1><% }; %>
```

Will be translated to something like this C# code:

```
Action action = () => { Response.Write("<h1>Title</h1>"); };
```

Once you understand this, it's no different than other methods: for each cell, Telerik simply call the `Action` you wrote without realizing it, which contains one or more `Write` calls generated by the compiler.